# best way to update regularly already pushed feature branch with master

Tags: git

I wonder what is the best way to regularly update my feature branche with commits which are done on the master branch. Indeed, when my feature branch is still not pushed, I rebase it on master and my history is very clean. But from the moment when I pushed it, if I try to rebase it on master I often have duplicated commits.
To avoid theses duplications my solution right now is to use a git merge instead a git rebase command once the feature branch is pushed (And I do not want force push because of other users). It works well but introduced lot of "git merge commit point"...

How to avoid this ? is it possible to regularly update my feature branch (which is already commit) to finnaly do my favorite commands that works well on not pushed branch and have a very nice history:

```
 git checkout my-feature 
 git rebase master 
 git checkout master 
 git merge my-feature --no-ff
```

Comment: Do you actually see your commits duplicated after a rebase? That would be odd. Note that `10 / 8` means 10 outgoing commits, 8 incoming commits. You simply need to do a `git push --force` to update your remote branch, which will move the branching point to the head of the master, with your 2 commits still on the other branch

Comment: @Pieterjan I already used `git push --force` when I work alone on that branch but it seems to be a very bad practice if other people work on that branch, isn't it ?

Comment: "if other people work on that branch" - I think so. It probably wouldn't be a problem if the others would stash their changes, first pull the feature branch, then apply the changes again. But they'd absolutely have to pull first before doing commits themselves and force-pushing. The rule of thumb is to have only one person working on a seperate branch.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, when I want to get updates from main branch, I just merge into my feature branch. And when it's time to merge back to main, I just squash and merge directly. 1 commit, very clean, has all the changes you made in feature branch as one, avoids confusion, easy to track.